# Kill android app

Tags: android, process, kill

I'm starting a external app with startActivity. But later I also need to stop/kill this app. I tried some things with killProcess or restartPackage but that's not working. Maybe lollipop is blocking this?

Regards
Daniel

Comment: Android system allows to open the external app but not to close it

Comment: Don't do that.  You can jump back into the foreground by sending yourself an intent, but the user may find it a bit rude!

Comment: @ChrisStratton That's not the problem. It's a private app.

Comment: Private or public, you can still get into a war where Android restarts what you have killed.  It's the wrong way to do things - focus on what the user sees, and let Android decide what should be running.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You are right. I programmed now the needed feature from the other app directly into mine so I don't need the other app anymore..

Answer (score 0):

You can't on stock device. If you have a rooted device you can kill the process by Runtime exec but in any case this isn't the best thing to do for me...